# plot vlines with matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot vertical lines in a log plot

```
xv1 = 10

plt.semilogy(t,P,'b')
plt.semilogy(t,Pb,'r')
plt.vlines(xv1,-1,1,color='k',linestyles='solid')
plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
plt.ylabel('P [Pa]')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The vlines does not show up in the plot (it does for plt.plot)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you also include some (fake?) data with your code?  It is hard to test if don't know what you inputs are.

Comment: Why do you use a semi-lograithmic plot (which cannot contain values `y=0`) and still want your vertical line to extend from -1 to 1? If you want to have a line extending across the entire figure, you should probably use `axvline`.

Comment: @DavidZwicker Completely missed the semi-log.... What version of mpl are you using?  There has been some tweaking in how clipping of undefined values is handled in log plots.

Comment: As an additional remark: if you do wish to plot data that is also negative on a log axis use `ax.set_yscale("symlog")`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For plotting vertical lines that span the entire plot range, you may use `axvline`. Your code could then read

```
xv1 = 10

plt.semilogy(t, P, 'b')
plt.semilogy(t, Pb, 'r')
plt.axvline(xv1, color='k', linestyle='solid')
plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
plt.ylabel('P [Pa]')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```